# XSLT: How to loop for each unique nodes with multiple subnodes as key field?

Tags: xslt, foreach

```
<A>
    <B>
        <C>
            <Name>John</Name>
            <Age>21</Name>
            <Sex>Male</Name>
        </C>
        <C>
            <Name>John</Name>
            <Age>50</Name>
            <Sex>Male</Name>
        </C>
        <C>
            <Name>John</Name>
            <Age>21</Name>
            <Sex>Male</Name>
        </C>
    </B>
</A>
```

I just want to know how to loop for each unique node "C". A node "C" is unique if it has a different "Name", "Age", and "Sex" subnodes.

I'm expecting to loop to the 2 "C" nodes based on the sample above.

Comment: could you please show us whts your expected result.

Comment: I'm expecting to loop only to the first two "C" nodes (21 and 50 year old John).

Comment: The 3rd "C" node is just a duplicate of the 1st "C" node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This i a grouping issue. The "normal" solution with xslt-1.0 is **muenchian grouping** (e.g look to [this](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)).

Therefor add a key to your xslt for your grouping condition:

```
<xsl:key name="kUniqueC" match="C"  use="concat(Name,'|', Age, '|', Sex)"/>
```

Loop over groups:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//C[
             generate-id() = generate-id(key('kUniqueC', concat(Name,'|', Age, '|', Sex))[1])
              ]" >
```

Try this:

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//C[
         generate-id() = generate-id(key('kUniqueC', concat(Name,'|', Age, '|', Sex))[1])
          ]" >
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Output:

```
<C>
  <Name>John</Name>
  <Age>21</Age>
  <Sex>Male</Sex>
</C><C>
  <Name>John</Name>
  <Age>50</Age>
  <Sex>Male</Sex>
</C>
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
<xsl:template match="A/B">
   <xsl:for-each select="C">
       <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::C[Name = current()/Name and Age = current()/Age and Sex = current()/Sex])">
          <xsl:value-of select="Name" />, <xsl:value-of select="Age" />
       </xsl:if>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

This will output Name, Age for the first 2 C nodes.

Comment: Thanks Marcus for your quick answer!

Comment: appreciate this answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<div>
  <xsl:for-each select="A/B/C">
    <xsl:variable name="name" select="Name"/>
    <xsl:variable name="age" select="Age"/>
    <xsl:variable name="sex" select="Sex"/>

    <xsl:variable name="numEntries" select="count(//C[Name=$name][Age=$age][Sex=$sex])"/>
<xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />

<xsl:choose>
 <xsl:when test="$numEntries=1">
       <p><xsl:value-of select="Name" /></p>
       <p><xsl:value-of select="Age" /></p>
       <p><xsl:value-of select="Sex" /></p>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$i &gt; $numEntries">
       <p><xsl:value-of select="Name" /></p>
       <p><xsl:value-of select="Age" /></p>
       <p><xsl:value-of select="Sex" /></p>
</xsl:when>
 </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each>
</div>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```